# Adding scrollbars to JTextPane inside a JTabbedPane?

Tags: java, swing

I have JTextPanes which are added to a JTabbedPane.

How do I get the JTextPanes to have vertical scrollbars?

I've tried wrapping the JTextPane inside a JScrollPane and adding the JScrollPane to the JTabbedPane but none of the text shows.

Comment: Could you post the code that you mentioned? Because that is how the scrollbars in swing work. There is likely a small bug in your code that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I get it to work, the code below produces this screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws BadLocationException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");

        JTabbedPane tabs = new JTabbedPane();

        JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
        textPane.getDocument().insertString(0, "Hello World!", null);
        tabs.addTab("Test", new JScrollPane(textPane));

        frame.add(tabs);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I figured out the problem: I was calling textPane.setText() instead of textPane.getDocument().insertString()

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the JTextPane onto a JScrollPane and then add the JScrollPane to the panel/tabbedpane.

See this code sample:

```
JTextPane txtpn = new JTextPane();
JScrollPane scrl = new JScrollPane(txtpn);
myTabPane.add(scrl); //Or whatever you call that pane
```

*I haven't tested this, but it works perfect with other JComponents on JPanels*

Hope it helps.

Comment: I've tried that but none of the text displays. I also tried changing the JTextPane to a JTextArea and I get the same result.

Comment: Strange, try `dacwe`'s solution.